# Testing enviroment loads with jquery error

Tags: meteor, mocha.js

I’m trying to add testing to my Meteor 1.8 application and I’m following the documentation.

When I run: `npm run test-app` to start the app in test mode

```
"test-app": "TEST_WATCH=1 meteor test --full-app --driver-package meteortesting:mocha --port 3050"
```

the browser states that I’m missing jquery. jquery is installed using npm not atmosphere.

What am I suppose to do here?

**UPDATE**

ERROR MESSAGE IN CONSOLE

`Uncaught Error: Cannot find package "jquery". Try "meteor add jquery".`

Path: `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "reactproject",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run --settings settings-dev.json",
    "test": "meteor test --once --driver-package meteortesting:mocha --port 9999",
    "test-app": "TEST_WATCH=1 meteor test --full-app --driver-package meteortesting:mocha --port 3050",
    "visualize": "meteor --production --extra-packages bundle-visualizer",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .jsx --fix"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": "eslint --fix",
    "*.jsx": "eslint --fix"
  },
  "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.3.4",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "validator": "^10.11.0"
  },
  "meteor": {
    "mainModule": {
      "client": "client/main.jsx",
      "server": "server/main.js"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.4.9",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "css-mqpacker": "^7.0.0",
    "postcss-csso": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-load-config": "^1.2.0",
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {
        "browsers": [
          "last 2 versions",
          "> 2%"
        ]
      },
      "css-mqpacker": {},
      "postcss-csso": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the full `package.json` content and also the full error stack?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I've updated the question